custom label renderer for react-dropdown-tree-select
I want to render some custom html in  label in react-dropdown-tree-select. I want to achieve something like this. How can i achieve this

https://dowjones.github.io/react-dropdown-tree-select/#/story/with-bootstrap-styles
